# How would you name a chief administrator role?

Tags: synonyms, appropriate

Say, I have an administrative role in my software application which is intended to assign other roles among other administrators. So I'm looking for a simple and clear name for that senior administrator role.

So far I only got one idea - *principal*. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Principal already has a use in user management, roughly "user or role or group: something you can give a right to/something that can be authenticated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with are "**leader**" and "**chief**". Yes, chief itself can be used also.

But in your specific role, one word would not be enough because there are also other administrators and I don't think that your only duty is assigning roles.

"**chief administrator**" is the best phrase.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like that particular role is for *security*, and therefore anyone who has that role assigned to them is a *security administrator*.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps **allocator** (form *[allocate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/allocate)*)

> to set apart for a specific purpose

Or maybe **designator** (from *[designate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/designate)*)

> to select or name for an office or duty; appoin